# md-toolbar not rendering as material toolbar using angular material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I'm using angular material v1.1.0 and trying to create a simple toolbar. I've taken the code from angular material demo, but the toolbar being rendered, instead getting individual elements. Not sure what I'm missing.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial', 'ngRoute']);
```

```html
    <html ng-app="app">
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        
        <title>My App</title>

     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
      </head>

      <body>
        <md-content>
         <md-toolbar>
          <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
           <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="menu">
            <md-icon md-font-set="material-icons">menu</md-icon>
           </md-button>
           <h2>
            <span>My App</span>
           </h2>
           <span flex></span>
           <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="menu">
            <md-icon md-font-set="material-icons">whatshot</md-icon>
           </md-button>
           <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="menu">
            <md-icon md-font-set="material-icons">share</md-icon>
           </md-button>
           <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="menu">
            <md-icon md-font-set="material-icons">file_download</md-icon>
           </md-button>
           <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="menu">
            <md-icon md-font-set="material-icons">thumb_up</md-icon>
           </md-button>
          </div>
         </md-toolbar>
        </md-content>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: can you create a plunker at the same time what error are you facing ?

Comment: I've created a code pen http://codepen.io/biznetboost/pen/RoxNaY
Check the appearance and you'll understand

Comment: Have you taken example from somewhere and it is not working in your code pen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add `rel="stylesheet"` while loading the angular-material css. Working pen here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jVYEdM